# Page won't scroll in mobile devices

Tags: css, iphone, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm building a Wordpress site on Twitter Bootstrap and it's looking good in all resolutions, except it absolutely will not scroll in mobile devices such as my iPhone. It scrolls fine in mobile resolution emulators like responsivetest.net, but when I view the site on my phone it will not scroll.

For testing purposes I tried this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    html, body, #content {
        height: 2000px !important;
        overflow: scroll !important
    }
```

But there was no change on my phone after cache refresh.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: If you leave out the fixed height of 2000px, does this resolve the issue?

Comment: I think you have to explain for us why you are fixing the height to 2000px first. If you want a larger page than you've got content - try min-height instead without overflow scroll.